# urls django, NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, django-templates, reverse, django-urls

I have this error and I don't know it's origin :

**NoReverseMatch at /PROJETTEST/rec
Reverse for 'myp' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P\w+)$']**

```
 url(r'^allp$', allp.as_view(), name="allp"),
 url(r'^allp/(?P<slug>[^/]+)$',ficheP.as_view(), name="ficheP"),

 url(r'^(?P<namep>\w+)$','myp', name="myp"),
 url(r'^(?P<namep>\w+)/members$','members', name="members"),
 url(r'^(?P<namep>\w+)/rec','rec', name="rec"),


    <a href="{% url 'myp' p.name %}" role="button">Gen</a>
    <a href="{% url 'members' p.name %}" role="button">Members</a>
    <a href="{% url 'rec' p.name %}" role="button">rec</a>
```

I have when I want access to ..//rec..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p.name` is an empty string in your template.  While `myp` url requires at least one alphanumeric character as the argument.

Comment: So why only rec don't work ? Because myp and members work so p.name is not empty

Comment: Read the error message carefully. The reverse doesn't work for the first `{% url %}` tag in the template with is `{% url 'myp' p.name %}`.

Comment: So why when I click on <a href="{% url 'myp' p.name %}" role="button">Gen</a> it works ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I understood the problem but i didn't know the reason. I had a problem in my view ! Thank you both

Comment: Because you do it on the other view (not the `/rec/`) which passes non-empty `p.name`.